# Reduce gain of charge amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, gain, piezo

I have a circuit for measuring piezo signals, roughly based on [Analog Devices CN0350](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/reference-designs/circuits-from-the-lab/cn0350.html). It contains a charge amplifier that converts the piezos' charge to a voltage signal.

[image]

When measuring signals of high amplitude the output signal (OUT) can reach both GND and VDD levels, which means the charge amplifier itself is clipping. I am looking for a way to reduce the gain of the charge amplifier to fit those high-amplitude signals into my measurement range.

In general the output gain is proportional to 1 / C1, but C1 is already quite large and I would prefer to keep it that size (I'm using C0G/NP0 type SMD caps and don't want to go bigger than 0603).

Is there another way to reduce the gain other than increasing C1? I am looking for a reduction to approx. 1/4 of the current gain.

VDDA is 3.3 V.

Comment: 15 nF is "quite large"?

Comment: `proportional to 1 / C2`; a hint: the output gain is proportional to 1 / (**R2** \*C2). Also, to accommodate the circuit to a wider dynamic range, you can consider using a logarithmic preamplifier or automatic gain control

Comment: Why can't you increase C1?

Comment: Yes, a typo in the OP, and also migrated into my comment. The question (I guess) should read '... proportional to 1 / C**1**'; my comment should read 'proportional to 1 / (**R2** \*C1)'.

Comment: The only way is to increase C1.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I edited my Question. I can increase C1, but I am looking for alternative ways to reduce the gain (See updated question)

Comment: Increase R1? . .

Comment: @V.V.T For charge to voltage responsivity, R2 isn't a factor. It cuts high frequencies and provides some circuit protection (piezos can make a lot of volts).

Comment: @JohnDoty How could I disregard word 'piezo' written so many times in the question, maybe a passing blackout. Was more concerned to find a C1 counterpart. Still, won't delete the comment right away, maybe it would direct the OP to a current-shunt line of thought